# AMD PC hangs when booting from live DVD (or USB stick)

Tags: boot, live-usb, livedvd

I’m attempting to upgrade a 2004 PC currently running Win XP to Lubuntu 16.04, but have had no success from DVD or USB.
An error message appears briefly:
“Spectre V2 mitigation: lfence not serialising. Switching to generic retpoline”.

Booting then continues to GUI which appears functional for about one minute before the mouse freezes and the keyboard is ignored. The problem afflicts both the “Install” and “Try” options and seems related to time rather than anything I’m attempting to do. Indeed, even if I don’t make a selection it still hangs after a couple of minutes.

I’ve tried numerous other Linux varieties including the i386 version, all behave in a similar way. LinuxLite launched in safe mode mentioned:
“no caching mode page found, assuming drive cache: write through” before continuing with lots more logging info, eventually hanging with:
“BUG: Bad rss counter state MM:ffff800093efbc00  idc:0 val:3
BUG: Bad rss counter state MM:ffff800093efbc00  idc:2 val:-1”

Motherboard is ASUS with AMIBIOS V0403
Processor is AMD Athlon 64 3200+
Graphics: on-board NVidia Geforce 6100

Can anyone suggest what I’m doing wrong?

Comment: 0. How much RAM is there?; 1. Maybe the RAM is bad. You can test it with **memtest** from the boot menu; 2. It is an old computer, so it might work better with **Lubuntu 14.04.1 LTS** (with the Trusty kernel series), 3.13. You can also try the Puppy Linux flavour **TahrPup** or **Wary Puppy** or **Tiny Core**; 3. An alternative is to install **Ubuntu Server** 14.04.1 LTS or 16.04.1 LTS, which are text mode linux versions; 4. See also this link, [Old hardware brought back to life](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2130640)

Comment: @sudodus
Thanks for the reply.
RAM checks out OK, 2496MB present. Lubuntu 14.04.1 LTS locks up just as everything else I've tried. In the few tens of seconds available the system does appear to be functional which suggests that the PC is suspect… yet the thing is stable when running XP.

Comment: You have enough RAM and it checks out OK :-) So the problem is somewhere else. I know that the new linux drivers have problems with some old graphics chips/cards. This is why I suggested that you try **Wary Puppy**, which is old, and known to work well with old hardware. It is also possible, that something is wrong on the motherboard, for example a crack (physical crack in a connection), that will break the electric connection after a while because of thermal expansion.